# get strlen after memcpy in c++

Tags: c++, memcpy, strlen

i`m trying to concatenate a characters using memcpy function, however, i kinda get a weird length of my buffer after couple of memcpy. please see code below

```
int main()
{
uint8 txbuffer[13]={0};
uint8 uibuffer[4] = "abc";
uint8 rxbuffer[4] = "def";
uint8 l[2]="g";
int index = 1;

cout << strlen((char*)txbuffer) <<endl;
memcpy(&txbuffer[1],&uibuffer, strlen((char*)uibuffer));
index+=strlen((char*)uibuffer);

cout <<"after first memcpy: "<< strlen((char*)txbuffer) <<endl;
memcpy(&txbuffer[index],&rxbuffer, strlen((char*)uibuffer));

cout <<"after second memcpy: "<< strlen((char*)txbuffer) <<endl;
memcpy(&txbuffer[0],&l, strlen((char*)l));

cout <<"after third memcpy: "<< strlen((char*)txbuffer) <<endl;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(txbuffer); i += 1)
{
    cout << (int(txbuffer[i]))<<" : "<< char(int(txbuffer[i]))<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

the output is:

```
after first memcpy: 0
after second memcpy: 0
after third memcpy: 7
103 : g
97 : a
98 : b
99 : c
100 : d
101 : e
102 : f
0 : 
0 : 
0 : 
0 : 
0 : 
0 :
```

my question is why after the first memcpy, the strlen of the buffer still is zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the first character in `txbuffer` is the null character `\0`. (You initialized it this way.) So the string effectively has zero-length when you print it out.

You didn't overwrite the first character in the first or second copies. But you finally do overwrite it in the 3rd copy. That's why the length is zero until after the 3rd copy.

```
//  Start
{  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0}

//  After 1st memcpy(): strlen() is still zero
{  0, 'a', 'b', 'c',   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0}
   ^ first null character

//  After 2nd memcpy(): strlen() is still zero
{  0, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0}
   ^ first null character

//  After 3rd memcpy(): strlen() is now 7
{'g', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0}
                                      ^ first null character
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not `strlen` destination after `memcpy`ing `strlen` bytes from the original, because you didn't copy the 0-terminator.

Besides, you copy starting at byte 1, not 0, meaning `strlen` is 0, because your array is initially zeroed (that kind of makes my first paragraph irrelevant, but you should be aware of it).

Answer (score 0):

`strlen()` counts the number of non-NUL bytes.  Since the initial NUL remains after the copy, of course `strlen()` returns zero.

Instead, you might prefer using `sizeof` or some more explicit concatenation logic:

```
int main()
{
    char txbuffer[13];
    char uibuffer[4] = "abc";
    char rxbuffer[4] = "def";
    char l[2]="g";
    int index = 1;

    int n = sprintf (txbuffer, "%s%s%s", uibuffer, rxbuffer, l);
    cout << "buffer has " << n << " bytes" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple issues here.

first of all using &uibuffer as argument to memcpy is wrong, just use `uibuffer (rxbuffer,l)` since they are already an addresses (being arrays):

```
memcpy(&txbuffer[1], uibuffer, strlen((char*)uibuffer));
```

doing a strlen on the above txbuffer (since you copy to the txtbuffer with offset 1) will yield 0 length since strlen counts until it finds \0, using strlen in combination with memcpy isn't a good idea instead keep track of the length you have in txtbuffer manually, you know the lengths of the strings you copy in and the offsets.